# Chart.JS custom y axis labels with text that has value

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I want to make a bar graph like this.. is it possible in chart.js?

[image]

assuming that OK, Difficult, and Problematic has its own value..

Example:

- Problematic = 11 or more
- Difficult = 6 - 10
- OK = 0 - 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
options: {
            scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                userCallback: function(value) {
                    return value;
                },
                stepSize: 1
              }
            }]
          },
        },
```

You can also set the step size.